CSRF Cookie Django/React
I have issue with CSRF token in Django and React and i can't find solution.
The problem show up when I want to update the product thumbnail
This is problem:
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /admin/product/15/api/products/upload/
[23/May/2024 18:36:32] "POST /admin/product/15/api/products/upload/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2960
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser

from base.models import Product
from base.serializers import ProductSerializer


@api_view(["GET"])
def get_products(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(["GET"])
def get_product(request, pk):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = ProductSerializer(product, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
def create_product(request):
    user = request.user

    product = Product.objects.create(
        user=user,
        name="Sample Name",
        price=0,
        brand="Sample Brand",
        count_in_stock=0,
        category="Sample Category",
        description="",
    )

    serializer = ProductSerializer(product, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(["PUT"])
@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
def update_product(request, pk):
    data = request.data
    product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)

    product.name = data["name"]
    product.price = data["price"]
    product.brand = data["brand"]
    product.count_in_stock = data["count_in_stock"]
    product.category = data["category"]
    product.description = data["description"]

    product.save()

    serializer = ProductSerializer(product, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(["DELETE"])
@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
def delete_product(request, pk):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)
    product.delete()
    return Response("Produkt został usunięty.")


@api_view(["POST"])
def upload_image(request):
    data = request.data

    product_id = data["product_id"]
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)

    product.image = request.FILES.get("image")
    product.save()

    return Response("Obraz został załadowany")


import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link, useParams, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Loader from "../components/Loader";
import Message from "../components/Message";
import FormContainer from "../components/FormContainer";
import { listProductDetail, updateProduct } from "../actions/productActions";
import { PRODUCT_UPDATE_RESET } from "../constants/productConstants";

function ProductEditScreen() {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
    const [image, setImage] = useState("");
    const [brand, setBrand] = useState("");
    const [category, setCategory] = useState("");
    const [count_in_stock, setCountInStock] = useState(0);
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
    const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
    const { error, loading, product } = productDetails;

    const productUpdate = useSelector((state) => state.productUpdate);
    const {
        error: errorUpdate,
        loading: loadingUpdate,
        success: successUpdate,
    } = productUpdate;

    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(
            updateProduct({
                id: id,
                name,
                price,
                image,
                brand,
                category,
                count_in_stock,
                description,
            })
        );
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (successUpdate) {
            dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_UPDATE_RESET });
            navigate("/admin/product-list");
        } else {
            if (!product.name || product.id !== Number(id)) {
                dispatch(listProductDetail(id));
            } else {
                setName(product.name);
                setPrice(product.price);
                setImage(product.image);
                setBrand(product.brand);
                setCategory(product.category);
                setCountInStock(product.count_in_stock);
                setDescription(product.description);
            }
        }
    }, [dispatch, product, id, navigate, successUpdate]);

    const uploadFileHandler = async (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("image", file);
        formData.append("product_id", id);

        setUploading(true);

        try {
            const config = {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                },
            };

            const { data } = await axios.post(
                "api/products/upload/",
                formData,
                config
            );

            setImage(data);

            setUploading(false);
        } catch (error) {
            setUploading(false);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Link to="/admin/product-list">Powrót</Link>

            <FormContainer>
                <h1>Edytuj produkt</h1>
                {loadingUpdate && <Loader />}
                {errorUpdate && <Message variant="danger">{errorUpdate}</Message>}

                {loading ? (
                    <Loader />
                ) : error ? (
                    <Message variant="danger">{error}</Message>
                ) : (
                    <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                        <Form.Group controlId="name">
                            <Form.Label>Nazwa</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                type="name"
                                placeholder="Wprowadź nazwę"
                                value={name}
                                onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                            ></Form.Control>
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group controlId="price">
                            <Form.Label>Cena</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                type="number"
                                placeholder="Wprowadź cenę"
                                value={price}
                                onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)}
                            ></Form.Control>
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group controlId="image">
                            <Form.Label>Miniaturka</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Załaduj obraz"
                                value={image}
                                onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.value)}
                            ></Form.Control>

                            <Form.Control
                                type="file"
                                id="image-file"
                                label="Wybierz obraz"
                                onChange={uploadFileHandler}
                            ></Form.Control>
                            {uploading && <Loader />}
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group controlId="brand">
                            <Form.Label>Marka</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Wprowadź markę"
                                value={brand}
                                onChange={(e) => setBrand(e.target.value)}
                            ></Form.Control>
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group controlId="count_in_stock">
                            <Form.Label>Stan magazynowy</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                type="number"
                                placeholder="Wprowadź stan magazynowy"
                                value={count_in_stock}
                                onChange={(e) => setCountInStock(e.target.value)}
                            ></Form.Control>
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group controlId="category">
                            <Form.Label>Kategoria</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Wprowadź kategorię"
                                value={category}
                                onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.target.value)}
                            ></Form.Control>
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group controlId="description">
                            <Form.Label>Opis</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Wprowadź opis"
                                value={description}
                                onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
                            ></Form.Control>
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Button className="mt-3" type="submit" variant="primary">
                            Aktualizuj
                        </Button>
                    </Form>
                )}
            </FormContainer>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ProductEditScreen;



Share a [example]. Share the code of all your dispatches.
